# Show that $\pi(Z)$ acts as a scalar over $\mathbb{g}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, representation-theory, lie-algebras, group-actions

Let $(\pi, V)$ be a finite dimensional irreducible representation of $\mathbb{g}$

$V$ is a vector space of homogeneous polynomials in 3 variables of degree d over $\mathbb{R}$

$\mathbb{g}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & a & b\\
0 & 0 & c \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $ where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{C}$

For example, $X=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $, $Y=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $ and $Z=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $

The basis for $\mathbb{g}$ is $\{X, Y, Z \}$

> Show that $\pi(Z)$ acts as a scalar.

To do this I think we need to show that $\pi(Z)$ is an intertwining operators between $\pi$ and itself, then the result follows from Shur's lemma

But how do we show it is an intertwining operator?
Thanks

Comment: What is $Z$? Presumably, it's $Z(\mathfrak g)$? Can you describe it more explicitly?

Comment: @GregorySimon Hi, I forgot to add that, I have edited my question with these details (it is a basis element)

Answer (score 0):

The Lie algebra is the complex $3$-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}_1(\mathbb{C})$. Since it is solvable, by Lie's theorem every finite-dimenisonal irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{h}_1(\mathbb{C})$ is $1$-dimensional.